# Run gnome-terminal in namespace

Tags: gnome-terminal, namespace

I enter a namespace with `unshare --net --mount`. When I run `xterm` in it, the shell in the windows that opens iherits the stuff from the namespace. When I run `gnome-terminal` it runs like I opened it from the desktop. Is there a way to run it "inside" the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2412507/4833070), running `gnome-terminal --disable-factory` makes it inherit the environment.